# SQLite Trigger error with ambiguous column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database due to the fact that I am working on Android.
My database looks like:

```
Lists(_id, name, weight, price), Products(_id, name, price, weight), Contains(_id, product, list, amount)
```

The weight of a list is the sum of the weights' contained products, same with prices. To keep it stable, I have designed the following trigger:

```
        CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS someTriggerName
        AFTER  DELETE ON products
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
         UPDATE lists
         SET price  = ( SELECT sum(p.price * c.amount) FROM contains c, products p WHERE c.list == _id AND c.product == p._id ),
           peso  = ( SELECT sum(p.price * c.amount) FROM contains c, products p WHERE c.list == _id AND c.product == p._id )
         WHERE _id IN (SELECT lists FROM contains WHERE product == OLD._id);
        END
```

It seems like the _id inside the SELECT cannot be there, but I don't know how to fix it. The error I have is:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: lists (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM products WHERE _id=1

Comment: `SELECT lists FROM...` what is the name of the column, `lists` or `list`?

Comment: It is the name of the table. I have copied it wrong to stackoverflow @forpas

Comment: `SELECT lists FROM contains WHERE product == OLD._id`. The column `lists` does not exist in `contains`.

Comment: Yes, that was the error. Thank you very much